# How to filter by input type?

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to write a Logstash configuration file. I have several `input`s. I tried like this, but it doesn't work.

```
input {
    file {
         type => "log"
         #...file from somewhere...
    }
    file {
         type => "log"
         #...file from another place...
    }
    file {
         type => "event"
         #...other settings...
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "log" {

        #...find comment patterns and drop it here...

        grok {
            match => { "message" => "...patterns here..." }
        }

        #...finally do some mutations here...

    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

When I comment out `if [type] == "log"`, then it works fine. How do I filter message only when the type matched?

Comment: That's how you do it.  Note that you first two inputs use type "log", so they'd both be processed by your grok{}.  If something else is going on, you'll need to describe what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I mean, the filter doesn't affect to type "log" so the output contains only "message" field, and it's not separated by the grok. If I don't use 'if' statement in the filter, then it works as I expected. I think there's something wrong with 'if' statement.

Comment: If grok{} fails, it will set a grokparsefailure tag; do you get this?  Have you tested your patten in the grok debugger?  Can you post a sample line and the pattern?

Comment: The grok{} itself is ok, it passes --configtest option, and it works if I don't use 'if' statement in the filter.